# What does this "before" mean?

Tags: grammar, literature

> He will also see, when the time comes, your enemies, and will carry them away like withered leaves **before** the autumn wind

What does *before* mean here?

Comment: Where did this come from? We have had this discussion before. Do not simply pull a quote out of thin air and ask what it means. Tell us where it came from. If you found it in a book, or a poem, or a song lyric, tell where it came from. If it is something you are writing, explain that as well.

Comment: I found the original text in *[Zwingli : Or, The Rise of the Reformation in Switzerland. A life of the reformer, with some notices of his time and contemporaries (1858)](https://archive.org/details/zwingliorriseof00chri)*, p.198, line 8 from the top of the page.

Comment: Off with his head!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a **poetic** figure of speech.

When leaves are blown away by wind, it is easy to imagine the wind pushing the leaves like a man pushing a cart:

The man is behind the cart when he pushes it, and the cart is before the man.

The same way, the wind is behind the leaves, pushing them, and the leaves are before the wind, being pushed.

For completeness, let's take the sentence apart a bit:

> He will also see, when the time comes, your enemies, and will carry them away like withered leaves before the autumn wind.

*When the time comes* means that something will happen at the right moment.

The main sentence describes two actions:

> He will see your enemies.
>   and
>   He will carry them away like withered leaves [are carried away] before the autumn wind.

So the way the "he" will deal with your enemies is compared to the way the autumn wind deals with withered leaves.

Anyone in a temperate climate has seen what happens to leaves in autumn: they fall down and dry out, shrivel (wither), then they get carried away by the wind - they disappear as if they were never there.

It is a strong image to describe what will happen to one's enemies...

Comment: It's about the *mightiness* than *the position*

Comment: @MaulikV - I am sorry, I don't seem to be able to parse your comment. _Than_ indicates a comparison, but I fail to see what you are comparing.

Comment: Your answer explains *the position of leaves and winds* whereas I think the sentence in question is about the comparison of leaves being blown away by the autumn wind (mightiness of the winds) and the enemies being blown away by the mightiness of **his** time.

Comment: The question was about the word _before_. If you feel the word _before_ expresses the _might_ of something, please elaborate that in an answer, because I don't see the point you seem to think is obvious :) Comparison to _what_?

Comment: My knowledge of the language is *nothing* before StoneyB's. :)

Comment: But does it get _carried away_ like leaves before wind? No, you describe a static situation of, indeed, comparison. How leaves and wind be compared, especially when with _carried away_ the author invokes exactly the interaction that we _know_ of them: the wind does the carrying, the leaves get carried.

Comment: Don't compare *leaves and wind.* Compare *the enemies with leaves and the wind with time.* The mighty time will blow away his enemies **as** the wind blows the withered leaves.

Comment: some problem, cannot log into chat. We get on it later.

Comment: Time performs no action in the sentence, expect that is "comes". The comparison is "HE will carry away your enemies, like the wind carries away leaves"

Comment: @username901345 - You want me to delete my answer? :)

Comment: no no maulik. you are correct ..this answer

Answer (score -3):

Actually before is used here in an uncommon sense. Look at this part only - 'withered leaves before the autumn wind.' it denotes the state of the leaves in the autumn wind or when the autumn wind blows.

Another example- A child's love for his parents is nothing before the parents' love for a child.

Comment: Remove the example and explain the answer a bit (preferably with references/links). It'll improve this answer. +1

Comment: Removing the verb _carry away_ from the comparison makes little grammatical sense. He will carry the enemies away like withered leaves _are carried away_ before the autumn wind.